# Trying to fill a screen with Apple Map

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, mkmapview

So on my app i have a screen where i want to display a map. Catch here is the map needs to rotate automatically as the user rotates the screen. Similar to when you press the compass button on any map.

I have coded the first part of creating a map and displaying it and rotating with compass.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        let rotation: Double = newHeading.magneticHeading * 3.14159 / 180
        //let point: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, -23)
        print(rotation)

        mapView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-CGFloat(rotation))

    }
```

Here are 4 screenshots of how the screen looks when i rotate at 4 different angels.
[image]

Issue is the way its displayed.

**Issue 1:** When i rotate there are white empty space and thats because my map won't scale. to screen size. How can i solve this?

**Issue 2:** The rotation is very cranky. Is there a way to make it smoother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing this the hard way.  You can use the [`userTrackingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setUserTrackingMode:animated:) property of the `MKMapView`.

If you set this property to `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` then the mapview will do the work for you.  You don't even need to implement the location manager delegate methods.

Comment: Yes working. Thanks!! I will accept this answer soon once Stack overflow allows it